# How do I show that $\langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle$ is not a radical ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

> Let $D$ be the affine algebraic set $V(Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X)$ in the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$. Show that $I(D) \neq \langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle$, and that $\langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle$ is not a radical ideal.

I know that by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $I(V(J))=\sqrt{J}$. If I can show that $\langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle$ is not radical, then $\sqrt {\langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle} \neq \langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle$.
I would have $I(D) \neq \langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle$

But how can I show that $\langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle$ is not a radical ideal?

Or if there is another (better) approach to this question?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1804010/173147, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2390937/173147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $\langle Y^2 - X^3 - X^2, X \rangle = \langle Y^2, X \rangle$. $Y^2$ is in this ideal but $Y$ is not, so the ideal is not radical. In fact, we can therefore compute its radical as $\langle X, Y \rangle$. Thus, $D = \{(0, 0)\} \subseteq \mathbb A^2$.